# Inserir imagem no fundo de listview vazio

Tags: android, listview, imageview

tenho um listview onde ele recebe os dados via Firebase. Porém se ele estiver vazio e para não ficar uma tela branca na Activity onde ele está, coloquei uma imagem de fundo igual ao exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu código onde está colocando a imagem. Ele faz um teste se o tamanho da listview for igual a 0, ele apresenta uma ImageView, caso contrário os dados.

```
if (listOnibusAtrasado.size() == 0 ){
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        arrayAdapterOnibusAtrasado.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listView_OnibusAtrasado.setAdapter(arrayAdapterOnibusAtrasado);
                        imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_smile);
                        txt_NenhumHorarioRelatado.setText("Nenhum Atraso Relatado pelos Usuários");

                    }else {

                        arrayAdapterOnibusAtrasado.sort(new Comparator<OnibusAtrasados>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(OnibusAtrasados o1, OnibusAtrasados o2) {

                                return o2.getHorário().compareTo(o1.getHorário());
                            }
                        });
                        arrayAdapterOnibusAtrasado.sort(new Comparator<OnibusAtrasados>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(OnibusAtrasados o1, OnibusAtrasados o2) {
                                return o2.getData().compareTo(o1.getData());
                            }
                        });

                        arrayAdapterOnibusAtrasado.notifyDataSetChanged();                       
                      listView_OnibusAtrasado.setAdapter(arrayAdapterOnibusAtrasado);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
```

Minha dúvida é, seria essa o jeito certo ? Pois o que estou fazendo é pegar uma imagem e um textview e colocando nesse teste (if else) que citei acima.

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa fazer nada disso. Basta usar o método `setEmptyView()` da ListView apontado para uma View ou ViewGroup qualquer do Layout XML e este será automaticamente carregado quando a lista estiver vazia.

Ex:

```
ImageView emptyView  = findViewById(R.id.image_empty);
ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
list.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```